# Docusign app getting error this page isn't working right now, local host can't currently handle this request, http error 500

Tags: asp.net-core, docusignapi

I'm developing an app based on the Docusign C# Quickstart.
Its working fine on my development PC (Win 11) in Visual Studio 2019 using IIS Express.
However, when I publish it to IIS (v10) on my development PC it runs and I can authenticate with Docusign just fine (once I got the proper redirect URI registered: https://localhost/ds/callback) but the step that actually sends the envelope is returning the following error in the browser:

This page isn't working right now.
Local host can't handle this request
http error 500

Any help is appreciated. I logged a support ticket with Docusign, but still waiting for a response.

Comment: I added some logging and it seems the APIClient basePath is different depending on if I'm running it from VS/IIS Express (demo.docusign.net/restapi) or from IIS (na4.docusign.net/restapi). I'm looking at the appsettings.json file and don't see any difference so not sure why that is happening yet.

Comment: This app has been promoted to production but I thought you could still test using the developer account.

Comment: ***Glad it's working now! Please check the most helpful answer to your question. Please upvote all useful answers***

Answer (score 0):

Quickstart is just an app to show you how to use DocuSign APIs.
The redirect after signing is back to localhost, and your app, once ready to be deployed to server, has to be set with a proper URL, at which point you'll need to update the redirect URI to the one based on your server.
The 500 error is coming from your app, not from DocuSign. You need to figure out   why your app cannot handle the URL that is set for redirect after signing by DocuSign.

Comment: Thanks Inbar. I added code to the quick start to get my app working. It connects to our SQL database and a folder of Word documents now. The app works in visual studio, but not when published to IIS.

Comment: Do you use localhost URL in IIS?

Comment: so what is not working? I'm confused

Comment: It turned out to be a couple of issues. One was my application pool identity needed to be a domain account with read permissions to the shared folder where the documents to send were, and the other was the folder path I had in appsettings was using a mapped drive letter when it should have been UNC. Its all good now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: glad it's working now Michael

Answer (score 0):

The base API address demo.docusign.net/restapi is used to reach the development/ test platform. The na4.docusign.net/restapi address is one of DocuSign's (many) production platforms.

Remember that, once you have passed the Go-Live process, you have **two** Client IDs (integration keys) one for the test platform, one for all of the production platforms. Each has its own settings.

### Added

The error

```
This page isn't working right now. 
Local host can't handle this request http error 500
```

Is from IIS. Use IIS logging to see the URL request that is coming in that can't be handled.

To see if it is the redirect from the initial OAuth Authorization Code grant URL, examine the initial URL redirect to account.docusign.com (prod URL).

The redirect contained as a query parameter in the initial OAuth redirect must:

1. Be correct for your instance of IIS.
2. Be allowed by your setting for the client ID (integration key) in DocuSign
   1, Be properly handled by your IIS and its app.

Comment: Thanks Larry. I understand what you are saying. I'm working back in the developer account with all its settings now and the app works fine in VS (its using the developer acct base URI), but when I publish it its trying to use the production account base URI even though the appsettings.json in the published folder looks identicle to the one in VS. I'm sure I'm doing something dumb but haven't been able to figure out what it is yet.

Comment: Update. I decided to delete everything from the IIS publish folder and re-publish and now it works in IIS on my dev box with the developer settings.

Comment: I have the app set up on another PC and using all the production account settings there and it works in VS. Its using the production base URI na4.docusign.net. When I publish it to IIS on that PC it is using the correct base URI but still crashing with the original error. Event viewer is not helping. I assume I need to learn how to turn on logging in the app or something. Right now I'm just writing a few parm values to a text file. Thats how I found out about the base URI issue.

Comment: Looks like the problem I'm having now is when the app is running in IIS it does not have permission to read the document I'm trying to send from the network share. I changed the identity value of the application pool being used to a domain user account and the shared folder gives read access to all domain users yet it still doesn't work.

Comment: Changing the shared folder path in the appsettings from a mapped drive to the UNC path fixed that.

Comment: App is working as designed now. Hopefully all my mentally challenged mistakes will help someone else.